# Can't update foreign key by passing parameter to stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreign-keys

I have an application which changes fields in a table. It's a simple form where the user can change the company associated with a group.

**.NET**

```
 public static string EditGroup(vw_Group_Model editGroup)
        {
            string outcome = "";
            if (editGroup.RowType == "ALF")
            {
                try
                {

                    using (SqlConnection conn = AlfOnlineConnection())
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        UserManager.Models.vw_Group_Model model = new vw_Group_Model();
                        using (var command = new SqlCommand("sp_UserManager_EditGroup", conn))
                        {
                            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            command.Parameters.Add("@CompanyId", SqlDbType.Int).SqlValue = editGroup.companyId;
                            command.Parameters.Add("@GroupId", SqlDbType.Int).SqlValue = editGroup.groupId;
                            //command.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).SqlValue = editGroup.selected_company;
                            //command.Parameters.Add("@GroupName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).SqlValue = editGroup.groupName;
                            command.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).SqlValue = editGroup.StartDate;
                            command.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).SqlValue = editGroup.EndDate;

                            switch (editGroup.IsActive)
                            {
                                case true:
                                    command.Parameters.Add("@isactive", SqlDbType.TinyInt).SqlValue = 1;
                                    break;
                                case false:
                                    command.Parameters.Add("@isactive", SqlDbType.TinyInt).SqlValue = 0;
                                    break;
                            }

                            int rowsEdited = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            if (rowsEdited == 1)
                            {
                                outcome = "Row successfully edited.";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    return ex.ToString();
                }
            }
```

**T-SQL**

```
USE [BradOnline]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_UserManager_EditGroup]    Script Date: 01/17/2013 13:11:05 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UserManager_EditGroup] 
@GroupId INT, 
@CompanyId INT,
                                                 --@GroupName   NVARCHAR(50), 
                                                 --@CompanyName   NVARCHAR(50), 
                                                 @StartDate  DATETIME,
                                                 @EndDate  DATETIME,
                                                 @isactive TINYINT

AS 
  BEGIN 


  DECLARE @AccountManagerId uniqueidentifier
  SET @AccountManagerId = '7A1DC75D-2628-4F8D-A376-9382A0762568'
  --(SELECT G.AccountManagerId FROM dbo.aspnet_Custom_Groups AS G
        --                  WHERE Id = @GroupId)


  --DECLARE @CompanyId BIGINT
  --SET @CompanyId = (SELECT MAX(c.Id) FROM dbo.aspnet_Custom_Companies AS c
        --                  WHERE c.Name = @CompanyName)



  UPDATE 
    [dbo].[aspnet_Custom_Groups]
SET 
    --[Name] = @GroupName,
    [StartDate] = @StartDate,
    [EndDate] = @EndDate,
    [IsActive] = @isactive,
    [AccountManagerId] = NULL,
    [CompanyId] = @CompanyId
WHERE 
    [Id] = @GroupId
  END
```

In the SQL if I hard-code the values for the update it works, but if i pass the values in it doesn't. I have been looking at it for ages but haven't gotten anywhere. The parameters in my application contain values when I check with a breakpoint

Comment: is there specific error that you get...?

Comment: Have you tried calling the Stored Procedure from native Query Analyser? If it works like that then the problem is in your .NET code otherwise it's in the SP - trying to narrow down the problem

Comment: @HmxaMughal It doesn't give me an error. I check the data and the row doesn't change for the companyId. For example if I change IsActive it works.

Comment: @ShaiAharoni It does compile. Once the code has run I have a grid which i can filter by name using ajax query.

Comment: do you have any triggers on aspnet_Custom_Groups table

Comment: I would use SQL Profiler to see exactly what parameters are passed to the SP. When you execute the SP manualy (not with .NET code) does it update your DB?

Comment: I think it may be .net code because I did execute query and it worked. I had to simplify the SP because I was confusing myself.

Comment: Do you know how to use SQL Profiler?

Comment: i agree with Shai Ahroni, use the SQL Profiler to trace the call to that sp and check to see what error you get...

Comment: I notice you're setting the values of the parms with SqlValue - I normally use .Value. E.g.command.Parameters.Add("@CompanyId", SqlDbType.Int); <br>command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = editGroup.companyId; <br>Worth a try?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting your parameter values through `SqlParameter.SqlValue`, try using `SqlParameter.Value` like below.

```
command.Parameters.Add("@CompanyId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = editGroup.companyId;
```